# Constructing Hamiltonian circuits in acyclic digraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

Any directed graph $G$ lacking cycles can acquire a Hamiltonian circuit through the addition of a sufficient number of edges.

> Q. Is there a method to minimize the addition of edges to achieve a Hamiltonian circuit?

Comment: Didn't you basically already ask this question?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790368/algorithm-for-finding-a-hamiltonian-path-in-a-dag/4790369#4790369

Can you just add one edge to that answer to answer this question?

Comment: Not exactly. It was about constructing a Hamiltonian path while preserving its acyclic nature. There is no such constraint here. Furthermore, the previous answer did not address my question adequately.

Comment: Why didn't the previous answer suffice? In your example there, I think you only need to add one edge, from node 19 to node 2.